# log of a matrix in R

Tags: r, if-statement, functional-programming

I have a matrix whose elements contain zeros and close to zero elements and I want to get a matrix with the logarithm of each one of the elements, considering `log0<-0` instead of `Inf` as it would give.

I tried:

```
takethelog <- function(A){
    if(A>0){
        return(logA)
    } else{
        return(logA <- 0)
    }
}
```

but it shows a warning:

```
In if (w > 0) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
>
```

What should I do ?

Answer (score 0):

```
mat <- matrix(sample(c(0, 0.001, 1, 23), 16, rep=T), 4, 4)
mat
#        [,1] [,2]   [,3]   [,4]
# [1,] 23.000   23  1.000  1.000
# [2,]  0.000    1 23.000  1.000
# [3,]  1.000   23  0.000  0.001
# [4,]  0.001    1  0.001 23.000
mat[mat>0] <- log(mat[mat>0])
mat[mat==0] <- 0

mat
#          [,1]     [,2]      [,3]      [,4]
# [1,]  3.135494 3.135494  0.000000  0.000000
# [2,]  0.000000 0.000000  3.135494  0.000000
# [3,]  0.000000 3.135494  0.000000 -6.907755
# [4,] -6.907755 0.000000 -6.907755  3.135494
```

Comment: You can make it quicker : `ifelse(mat>0,log(mat),0)`